# Direct raycasting from moving point A and moving Point B

Tags: c#, unity, vector, raycasting

I am attempting to raycast from Point A to Point A (both moving points).
I dont understand the comcept of raycasting (direction).

```
Update() {
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
    //Debug.Log (player.transform.position + " " + transform.position);

    Vector3 direction = (player.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
    Debug.Log (direction);
    Ray ray = new Ray (transform.position, direction);
    RaycastHit hit;

    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, direction, Color.red);

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 3f)) {
        gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
        //Debug.Log("OK");
    }
    else {
        gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.white;
    }
}
```

The problem i have right now is that.
When the player is below 0.88 on the Y Axis the enemy will turn blue. Else its white.
Enemy doesnt turn blue when player is very close to enemy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be a bit more clear about what you don't understand. It sounds like you're saying you don't understand the code you wrote.

Comment: I dont know how to be more clearer. Its just that the code doesnt work how i want it to work.

Comment: You can be more clear by telling us what part of the concept you don't understand. Just saying "I don't understand the concept" is very broad. What about it do you not understand?

Comment: For this current code that i have. I dont know why the enemy wont turn blue when it in range in term of the range (3f), it is always having a flashing blue.
I also dont know why its flashing aswell (blue and white). Why isn't the blue staying at a contain colour ?
And why it is that, when it is below 0.88 on the Y-Axis the enemy will stay at constant blue ?

Answer (score 0):

The block of code you posted is working fine.

First of all, be sure your player has a 3D collider ( box, capsule, etc ) in it.

Second, be sure to change the material color in one spot only. If the color is blinking, maybe you're changing it in two different updates.

Third, I don't think it is the source of the problem, but Unity documentation encourage you to do physics things in FixedUpdate instead of Update.

If everything above is right and you are still having problems, provide a bit more details, so I can try to help you out.

Comment: I think i found the problem. Its because in another script i am changing the collider.size of the player for collision detection. So right now im trying to fix that problem now.